# Opinion Based but relevant

Tags: discussion

As Data Science, we base much of our work on intuition and experimentation and this reflects on the kind of questions that end up been asked around DSSE.

Many times we want a recommendation or discuss something and it ends up becoming a long chat in the comments.

I am well aware that there is a chat feature in DSSE but it is quite hidden this is why I would like to publish a Discord server for this kind of talks and would like the help of high reputation members to build and manage it.

I've launched it here: https://discord.gg/NgjhVVA

Comment: Discussion and recommendations are different issues. I think that recommendations can stand as answers (some other sites in the network are like this, just not Stack Overflow) to relevant questions; about discussion, well, this feature might help indeed.